# how to check the windows taks services through unix batch

Tags: windows, unix, batch-file

Daily I am checking windows services by manualy (`start -> run ->services.msc`).

But i want to automat it through scripts.

How can I check the status (started or stopped) of the particular window service (eg.tomcat) using UNIX script(.bat)?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can use `sc query` or `net start` to do this.

For eg.

```
@echo off
sc query "ServiceName" | findstr RUNNING
if %ERRORLEVEL% == 0 goto working
echo Not Running
:working
echo Running
goto end
:end
```

or

```
@echo off
net start | findstr "ServiceName"
if %ERRORLEVEL% == 0 goto working
echo Not Running
goto end
:working
echo Running
:end
```

Comment: thank u user93353. Your Net Start code is working fine. I can able to retrived the service status. I have one question. I it possible to create one .bat file to retived different windows box service status. Ex. I have 3 different windows boxes(box1,box2,box3). In every box i have to test the particular service. Is it possible to create ONE .bat file to check the status of diff. box service status. If possible plz share the code. Thanks in advance.

Comment: Use the first parameter in the Batch file instead of the service name: `net start | findstr "%~1"` and place the desired service name when run the Batch file: `theFile.bat "ServiceName"`